# cURL POST method not working

Tags: php, curl, yii

I am using cURL to call a REST API. And the below code works for **GET method** , but however for **POST method** call it doesn't work after i add :

```
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

What could be the cause ?

```
$options = array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
                CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
                CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
                CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
                CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,    // Disabled SSL Cert checks
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('appId: C579929D-F0AA-4A8F-B6C6-1FF96694483C','appKey: AE78E7F1-FBDE-45F5-BAC2-210CEE9D3ED9')
               );

            $url = "some-url";
            $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            $output = curl_exec($ch);
            echo $output;
```

P.S

I double checked the API call using PostMan and it returns the expected result.

Do i need to add additional properties to API call ?

And i have to call REST API of format :

```
https://api.abc.com/v1/transactions/companyid/123/userid/456/description/ppeck/‌​source/PPA
```

And as suggested in the answer i have updated my code as :

```
        $url = "https://api.abc.com/v1/transactions";
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "companyid=12301&userid=31401&description=ppa-check&source=PPA&amount=123&txndate=010111&txntypeid=420&customerid=2701");
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

And sadly it didn't worked.

Comment: what fields you are posting?

Comment: i am appending it to the $url field : e.g `https://api.abc.com/v1/transactions/companyid/123/userid/456/description/ppeck/source/PPA`

Answer (score 2):

try
post fields must be as a query string with appending `(&)` like

```
    $url = 'http://example.com';  //your api call url
    $fields = 'q=example&y=fgt&ghty'; // all posting fields separated with &
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```

Comment: please show what you have tried update your question with new code

Comment: i am getting http code 596 :- service not found with your code?

Comment: it is obvious cause the URL doesn't exist .. i am testing on my local

Comment: TRY print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
   echo curl_error($ch); FOR ANY ERROR CHECK